# Add contact to Skype with Skype4py

Tags: python, skype, skype4py

I saw this thread:

[Skype4Py - How to successfully add a contact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490965/skype4py-how-to-successfully-add-a-contact)

and at the bottom this code:

```
sky = Skype4Py.Skype()
sky.Attach()
user = sky.SearchForUsers('someUser')
print user
```

and quote:

**Should get you a handle to add me for instance. Within the object that you recieve, there will be an option to add me for instance.**

So my question is "What function exactly within that object, because I found nothing like "addContact()" in docs???"

Here is link to docs:

http://skype4py.sourceforge.net/doc/html/

or option 2:

Should I go pressing buttons (sending events) trough client object?

```
sky = Skype4Py.Skype()
sky.Attach()

client = Skype4Py.client.Client(sky)
client.OpenAddContactDialog("someUser")
```

Simple 20 lines snippet would clarify this to me, because beside that docs link there are virtually any examples for skype4py on google.

Answer (score 0):

@Torxed pointed you at the method in his answer:

http://skype4py.sourceforge.net/doc/html/Skype4Py.user.User-class.html#SetBuddyStatusPendingAuthorization

Here's how you'd use it:

```
import Skype4Py
sky = Skype4Py.Skype()
sky.Attach()
requestMessage = "Please accept my request!"
searchResults = sky.SearchForUsers('echo123')
firstResult = searchResults[0]
firstResult.SetBuddyStatusPendingAuthorization(requestMessage)
```

Do be careful, though as this merely adds the FIRST result returned by the search. If you have the username exact, it should be fine.